# SSRS tooltip not displayed

Tags: ssrs-2012

Here is my SSRS version[image]

I added an expression in the tooltip field, but nothing is displayed on mouseover, in the preview, even when i deploy the report on the server, tooltip not work.

[image]

Any clue ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I even look at the source code of the report web page, and no code is there to display a tooltip.

Comment: Ok I found the problem, I cannot add numeric field into expression of a tooltip, it must be string value, so i added CSTR() everywhere, and my tooltip appears.

Comment: Your solution also worked for me too - please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @ToreØstergaard : done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, I cannot add numeric field into expression of a tooltip, it must be string value, so i added CSTR() everywhere, and my tooltip appears.